# How do I display a category name based on a segment?

Tags: ee2, segments, category-name, categories

I'm trying to show the `category_name` of `segment_3`. If I use the variable `{segment_3}` it displays the short name, I want to show the Full name. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd check out Cat2: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cat2

And you can use it like so...

> category_name from category_url_title

```
{exp:cat2:name category_url_title="{segment_3}" category_group="5"}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you sooo much. I don't know why I bothered trying to figure it out for a very frustrating hour. Again... Thanks.

Comment: Mark - remember to mark Nate's answer as "accepted" if it answered your question satisfactorily.

Comment: Ahhhh. Thanks... I didn't realize that's what you do. Thanks.

Comment: haha, you marked the wrong one!

Answer (score 5):

[**Low Seg2Cat**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-seg2cat) works great for this.

> Low Seg2Cat loops through the segments of the current URI, matches them against existing categories, and registers the matching categories as global variables, which you can use in your templates.

You'd be able to access your category name using `{segment_3_category_name}`

Comment: Also: [Low Title](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-title).

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Freebie](https://github.com/averyvery/Freebie) as well which would allow you to do:

```
{exp:freebie:category_name segment="3"}
```

Comment: There's also Seg2Cat as well, I thought that had been mentioned above already http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs

Those are usually my goto solutions because they're useful for so much.