# Get Category Name from a known Category ID

Tags: templates, channel, categories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display a category name based on a segment?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/how-do-i-display-a-category-name-based-on-a-segment)

I am trying to construct a Breadcrumb navigation system on my navbar. The URL will look like this: http://mysite.com/case_studies/index/3 - where '3' is a Category ID.

I want to be able to retrieve `{category_name}` or similar dynamically. How can I do this? I have seen `{exp:channel:categories}` but that seems to not let you filter by ID.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the [category heading](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/category_heading.html) tag pair?  Alternatively there is a great add-on from Low called [Seg2Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-seg2cat) that lets you grab a bunch of info on a category-related segment in the URL.